Homeomorphism between space and its quotient space
Let $X=\{(x, z, w) \in \mathbb{C}^3 : |x|=1, |z|^2+|w|^2=1 \}$, where $\mathbb{C}$ is the set of complex numbers. We consider the standard Euclidean topology on $X$ coming from $\mathbb{C}^3$. We further define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ as $(x_1, z_1, w_1) \sim (x_2, z_2, w_2)$ if $z_1=z_2$. My question is if $X$ and the quotient space $X/\sim$ are homeomorphic?
My attempt: Since the equivalence relation is defined on the last two components, I guess it is reasonable to check if the sets $S^3=\{(z, w) \in \mathbb{C}^3 :|z|^2+|w|^2=1 \}$ and $S^3/\sim$ are homeomorphic, where $(z_1, w_1) \sim (z_2, w_2)$ if $z_1=z_2$. Earlier I thought of finding the fundamental groups of $S^3$ and $S^3 /\sim$. It is a standard result that $S^3$ has fundamental trivial group. For $S^3/\sim$, since geometrically we are identifying two points with last same components, so we are pasting the upper and lower halves of $S^3$ with boundary intact. This gives an intuition that $S^3 / \sim$ has also the trivial fundamental group. But then it does conclude anything.

It appears that you have never voted. If you are happy with the answer below you should consider approving the answer. Otherwise, the question will remain lisited among unanswered questions.

$\Phi: X/\sim \to \overline{B_1(0)}\subseteq \mathbb{C}, [x,z,w] \mapsto z$ is a homeomorphism, since it is well-defined and injective since $[x_1,z_1,w_1] = [x_2,z_2,w_2] \iff  \Phi([x_1,z_1,w_1]) = z_1 = z_2 = \Phi([x_2,z_2,w_2])$. Thus $\Phi$ is continuous by the universal property of quotient topology. $\Phi$ is surjective, since for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z| \leq 1$ it is $(1,z,\sqrt{1-|z|^2}) \in X$ and $\Phi([1,z,\sqrt{1-|z|^2}]) = z$. Therefore $\Phi$ is a bijective and continuous map between a compact space and a Hausdorff space, i.e. $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism. Now, $X = S^1 \times S^3$ is not contractible but $X/\sim \cong \overline{B_1(0)}$ is, i.e. $X \ncong X/\sim$.
